# Plot specific data sets from arrays - Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

**Question**

I am a physicist with data that consists of 4 numpy.ndarrays, with equal lengths (the data I have is huge, with len ~75k). I am looking for a way to sort and plot data from the arrays.

Let's say I have arrays similar to `A,B,C,D` below:

```
A = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
B = [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2]
C = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
D = [5,6,3,6,3,5,2,4,6,8,7,9]
```

Let's now say I would like to do a 3D plot of `A,D,B' for each value of`C`. How could I automate this?

**Chosen solution**

With lots of help from RickardSjogren I wrote the following code to plot and save each of the data series for each value of C.

```
fig = plt.figure()
C_unique = np.unique(C)

for c in zip(C_unique):
    ax = axes(projection='3d')    
    ax.scatter(A[C == c], D[C == c], B[C == c])
    ax.set_xlabel('A')
    ax.set_ylabel('D')
    ax.set_zlabel('B')
    ax.set_title('C = '+str(c))
    savefig(saveDirectory+'/'+str(c))
    clf()
```

Comment: Can you explain more that what you mean by `3D plot of A,D,B' for each value ofC`?

Comment: Plot `A,D,B` as a `x,y,z` 3D projection plot, for each value of `C`. In the case of the arrays shown there, that would mean plot 2 plots of `A,D,B`, one where `C=1`, another where `C=2`.

Comment: So is this question related to those tags? if you are looking for a plotting answer you need to mention it! or maybe you want an array? anyway you need to add the code that you have been tried so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do 3D-plots using [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html). From the documentation you simply do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
```

And use the plotting methods of the [`Axes3D`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#module-mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d)-object referenced by `ax`.

An example using your data for arbitrary number of C-values:

```
import numpy as np

A = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2]
B = [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2]
C = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
D = [5,6,3,6,3,5,2,4,6,8,7]
A, B, C, D = map(np.array, [A, B, C, D])

fig = plt.figure()
c_unique = np.unique(C)
fig.set_size_inches(4 * len(c_unique), 4)

# Add axis for each unique C-value.
axes = [fig.add_subplot(1, len(c_unique), i + 1, projection='3d') for i, _ in enumerate(c_unique)]

for c, ax in zip(c_unique, axes):
    # Use boolean indexing of numpy-arrays to plot values for current C.
    ax.scatter(A[C == c], B[C == c], D[C == c])

    ax.set_xlabel('A')
    ax.set_ylabel('B')
    ax.set_zlabel('D')
    ax.set_title('C = {}'.format(c))

fig.tight_layout()
```

Result:

[image: 3D plot]

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to tweak your code for my purposes. This helped a lot.